# mkdirp is not creating recursively directory

Tags: node.js, recursion, mkdir

mkdirp is not creating recursively directory. if my location is : **'public/images/p/'+place_id+'/ls/';** and only i have till /p/ folder. in my case it is generating till place_id. can you help me out from this?

**part of code.**

```
var new_location = 'public/images/p/'+place_id+'/ls/';
var oldmask = process.umask(0);
mkdirp(new_location, '0777', function(err) {

process.umask(oldmask);

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else { console.log('success); }
});
```

Comment: output is success  but only 'public/images/p/1/' is creating.. but i want it to 'public/images/p/1/ls/' at a time.